# SQLite 3 Busy Exception in Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

```
SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email")
```

I get the above error when I try to migrate a migration (written below)

```
class AddIndexEmailUniquenessToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :users,:email,:unique => true 
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :users,:email
  end
end
```

what went wrong. I didnt do any lock kind of thing in previous transactions.

Comment: i got the error - there was a sandbox console open in my terminal and it had obtained a lock on the db. I will delete the above question. ;)

Comment: Another option is to answer the question yourself.  That way, some with the same issue will find your solution and check their console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a running process (rails console, ./script/server, etc) which is holding open connections to the database preventing the migration from modifying a table that's in use.

Kill off those.

If you can't find an obvious culprit, try:

```
ps aux | grep ruby
```

... to see a list of ruby processes that might be holding that db session.

Comment: Worth adding, I used putty terminal sessions, and I had to restart the session before it worked for me.